# how to write a query for a complex report with (sub)totals?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to write SQLite code to print a report in the form of the one listed below. Once I've generated the query, I will write a simple Python script to organize the information in the same fashion as below. The trouble that I'm having is to determine the query.

The database scheme I have is as follows:

```
Customer (customerID, lastName, firstName, age, gender, street, city, state, favorites, lastVisit)

LineItem (receiptID, lineNum, productID) Product (productID, flavor, kind, price)

ProductXSale(productID, saleID)

Rating (customerID, productID, score, comment)

Receipt (receiptID, purchaseDate, customerID)

Sale (saleID, startDate, endDate, percentOff)
```

I don't think we will need the Rating or Customer tables when building the query.

The hard part for me is determining the number of a product X on a certain day. To calculate this, we need to check each receipt on date Y and count how many times X appears on each receipt.

Another issue is if there is a sale happening at a point in time. So if product X goes on sale, then we need to report it at the reduced price.

Naturally, the income for each column is calculated by multiplying the number of a product sold by its price (checking to see if there is a sale).

Model report:

```
SALES REPORT FOR year-month

Product.id  Product.flavor  Product.kind  Product.price

    SALE DATE            NBR SOLD       INCOME
    date-of-purchase     number-sold    total-amount
    date-of-purchase     number-sold    total-amount
    date-of-purchase     number-sold    total-amount
    ⋮
    date-of-purchase     number-sold    total-amount

             TOTALS:  total-nbr-sold     total-total

Product.id  Product.flavor  Product.kind  Product.price

    SALE DATE            NBR SOLD       INCOME
    date-of-purchase     number-sold    total-amount
    date-of-purchase     number-sold    total-amount
    date-of-purchase     number-sold    total-amount
    ⋮
    date-of-purchase     number-sold    total-amount

             TOTALS:  total-nbr-sold     total-total

⋮

    GRAND TOTALS:            1234          999.99
```

I've tried several queries, and I'm just focusing on getting the number of each item sold per day. Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT P.id, P.flavor, P.kind, P.price, R.purchasedate
FROM Product AS P, Receipt AS R
GROUP BY R.purchasedate, P.id
ORDER BY P.id, DATE(R.purchasedate);
This produces something like:

id          flavor        kind      price       purchasedate
20-BC-C-10  Chocolate     Cake      8.95        2015-10-01
20-BC-C-10  Chocolate     Cake      8.95        2015-10-02
20-BC-C-10  Chocolate     Cake      8.95        2015-10-03
...
```

So essentially, this query just lists one item per day grouping by item.

Link to database: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6F5AA23EB67D4C49!107&authkey=!AHtA2TnLQUb5d9E&ithint=file%2cdb

Comment: You can't make that kind of report with just one query specially sqlite since it do not support any analytical functions. The alternative to to it would be lots of unions but that is not ideal. Your code could get all products (and info) and then another query for the sale date, nbr sold and income and with it calculates the totals on the application.

Comment: Your title basically contains no useful information - SQLite is in the tags; we know you're having trouble, you're posting here; "queries" - well, it's SQL, yes. Can you formulate a one-line question and use that as a title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you can get a number sold by joining the Product, LineItem, and Receipt then doing a count on the receipt ID:

```
SELECT P.id, P.flavor, P.kind, P.price, R.purchasedate, count(R.id) as numSold
FROM Product P join LineItem L on P.id = L.productID join Receipt R on L.receiptID = R.id 
GROUP BY R.purchasedate, P.id, P.flavor, P.kind, P.price
ORDER BY P.id, DATE(R.purchasedate);
```

To calculate the total, you could use sum(P.price), but you would probably need to join to the Sale table in order to account for the percent off.

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea. Thanks you!